# 17.04 cant install programs outside of software center

Tags: software-installation

Looking for a little help. I recently installed 17.04 and I can't install simple programs from the internet like chrome or brave browser or stacer. Those are the ones I have tried, but for each of them the package downloads as normal and then when I open the package it sends it to Software center and has a button for install. When I click on it nothing happens.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find a solution?

Comment: See [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](/q/66447/175814) for the general case. For applications that aren’t available in Canonical’s software repositories it depends on the specific application. You mention too different applications with different installation methods which makes this question difficult to answer. Please split it into individual questions for each piece of software. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble installing Brave, gave up for a while and tried again and finally got this to work:

```
$ wget -O brave.deb https://laptop-updates.brave.com/latest/dev/ubuntu64
$ sudo dpkg -i ./brave.deb
```

I got an error about missing dependencies. So I did this next:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I don't know what I did, I am really new at Linux, only had Ubuntu installed for about 2 months. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the .deb packages?
If so, you can use gdebi (GUI) or dpkg (Command Line) as the installer.

dpkg should be installed by default. You can install any *.deb package using this command. (open terminal where the file is located)

```
sudo dpkg -i stacer.deb
```

You can also use GDebi (a GUI program)
First you need to install gdebi

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then from your file manager you can open the .deb file using gdebi.